# C math and zero result

Tags: c

Not sure what the problem is here, but I keep getting the result of 0. The expected result is 0.2222222. I figure I must be assigning a zero to one of my variables but I can't figure out where this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double vs = 10;
    double rs = 100;
    double rl_start = 50;
    double rl_stop = 150;
    double rl_step = 5;

    double i, j;
    double n = rl_start;
    int count;

    do
    {
        j = ((rl_start) + (rl_step * count));
        i = (pow(vs, 2) * j) / pow((rs + j),2);
        printf("%lf", i);
        count++;

    }while(j <= rl_stop);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize `count` before using it:  `int count = 0;`

Comment: Hah, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for saving me another 30 minutes.